# PHP - call_user_func_array return a warning

Tags: php, mysqli

Following my code:

```
$query = mysqli_prepare($res, $my_query);
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $data[$key] = &$data[$key];
}
call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_param'), $data);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
mysqli_stmt_close($query);
```

The query works, but I found a warning in the log:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback
```

My PHP version is 5.5. How to solve it?

Comment: Just for reference, what does `var_dump($query)` give you?

Comment: @Darren bool(false), I found two more warning,  expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt boolean given in mysqli_stmt_execute and mysqli_stmt_close, but my query works.

Comment: You need to pass the mysqli object to the `call_user_func_array`

Comment: Looks like $query should normally be a mysqli statement object, and bind_param is a valid method of that object.  Since $query == false then mysqli_prepare failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
call_user_func_array([ClassName, Method], array $arguments);
```

The problem is that parameter 1 is an object in your case.

This should work

```
call_user_func_array(array('mysqli_stmt', 'bind_param'), $data);
```

Futhermore, mysqli_prepare returns false on error, so that would not be callable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have some questions. How to use call_user_func_array(array('mysqli_stmt', 'bind_param'), $data); with my query? Replacing call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_param'), $data); with call_user_func_array(array('mysqli_stmt', 'bind_param'), $data); my query doesn't work...

Comment: Your query is failing then. Make sure error reporting is one. `error_reporting(-1)`;

Answer (score 0):

The call to `mysqli_prepare()` is likely failing, returning a boolean. You need to check to see if `mysqli_prepare()` actually returns a `mysqli_stmt` object before trying to use it.

```
$query = mysqli_prepare($res, $my_query);
if (!$query) {
    throw new Exception('Error in preparing statement: ' . mysqli_error($res));
}
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $data[$key] = &$data[$key];
}
call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_param'), $data);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
mysqli_stmt_close($query);
```

Without this check, `$query` may be a boolean, which will of course not create a valid callback when used in the array passed to `call_user_func_array()`.

Furthermore, I would also recommend using the OO style when utilizing mysqli.

```
$connection = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password');

$statement = $connection->prepare($my_query);
if (!$statement) {
    throw new Exception('Error in preparing statement: ' . $connection->error);
}
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $data[$key] = &$data[$key];
}
call_user_func_array([$statment, 'bind_param'], $data);
$statement->execute();
$statement->close();
```